# Why do we now have Stack Overflow for Teams in sites that are not Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I was just going around Stack Exchange sites and I discovered this:

[image: Stack Overflow for Teams in Arqade Meta]

Any explanations why this is here? This is not Stack Overflow.

Comment: If this doesn't get answered, I'll wait for the [tag:featured] Meta SE post regarding this. This can't get migrated there anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [new change as of today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever):

> **Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Left Navigation update - will appear later this afternoon.**
>
> - If you belong to private Teams, Free or Basic, your Teams will be listed in the left navigation on most Stack Exchange sites. Currently, they appear only when you are visiting Stack Overflow.
> - If you don’t belong to any teams, there will be a prompt to start a team, which can be minimized.

Since we are one of most Stack Exchange sites, we now have teams in the left nav.

Comment: Currently, there is no way to dismiss the 'Teams - Create free Team' section in the left navigation, even via the "What's this?" link. One might need to use an ad blocker to remove that section.

Comment: Weird, I wonder what prompt can be minimized as described in the meta.SE post then.